# MediaStore query don't get all artists and camera videos

Tags: java, android, media-queries, mediastore

I use the code bellow to query all artists of music files, the method works good but the problem it's missing artist column called  and that column is visible in other music apps, so am I missing something in the query process ?

```
void loadAudioData() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getContentResolver();
        final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Artists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Artists._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Artists.NUMBER_OF_TRACKS};
        cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
            while (cursor.moveToNext())
                songsList.add(new Song(cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(3)));
        cursor.close();
        String sortType = sharedPreferences.getString("artist_sort", "artist a to z");
        boolean isReverse = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("artist_sort_isReverse", false);
        if (sortType != null)
            Song.sortArtist(songsList, sortType, isReverse);
    }
```

the same problem here too but with camera videos, the query process gets all videos except camera videos.

```
public List<ImageVideo> getAllVideos(){
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE};
        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
        Cursor cursor = Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                null, null, orderBy + " DESC");
        videoList = new ArrayList<>();
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                videoList.add(new ImageVideo(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(0)));
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        return videoList;
    }
```

Comment: What are camera videos?

Comment: try to get Artits from `MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST` in projection String

Comment: @blackapps videos captured by camera

Comment: Yes. By what else?

Comment: @blackapps what do you mean? 
my question is why cursor do not query videos captured by camera

Comment: Which other videos are shown? Videos by what else?

Comment: @GGK I tried but didn't help

Comment: then check, if in your audiofiles the artists are set in audio tag